# Header and footer in quarto qmd to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, latex, quarto

Anyone a suggestion how to set the header and footer of a #quarto .qmd #rstats pdf?
I tried this, but no footer shows:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: 
  pdf:
    include-in-header: 
      text: 
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
---
\fancyfoot[L]{Footer text}
# Chapter ONE
text
\newpage
# Chapter TWO
```

Can I use fancyhdr? If yes, how? If not, what then? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to use `fancyhdr` (see the answer by @Julian).

But also keep in mind that, Quarto uses KOMA-Script classes (`scrartcl` by default) and KOMA-Script suggests using `scrlayer-scrpage` latex package for handling header and footers instead of `fancyhdr`. See the [manual](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) chapter 05, p. 253.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: 
  pdf:
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
        \rohead{Header text}
        \lofoot{Footer text}
---

# Chapter ONE

text

\newpage

# Chapter TWO
```

You may also want to go through [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283670/understanding-headers-in-scrartcl) question and the corresponding answer on Tex StackExchange.

Comment: Prefect solution for the problem!

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer Shafee, with reasons why scrlayer-scrpage should be preferred to fancyhdr and links. I will change the accepted answer to yours, like Julian suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You are not that far away from the solution. If you want to use `fancyhdr`, this could work (note that you need to add `text: |` in order to have multiple lines of latex code):

```
---
format: 
  pdf:
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhead[C]{Header text}
        \fancyfoot[L]{Footer text}
---

# Chapter ONE

text
\newpage

# Chapter TWO
```

[image]